# Scrapy - how can I split the data in this table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from a table, however, the table data seems to have the same xpath. Here is an example of the table - http://www.hpft.nhs.uk/services/find-our-services/hertfordshire/cheshunt

And when I use `response.xpath('//td/text()').extract()` it returns the whole table.

I thought maybe I could use absolute xpaths, e.g. `response.xpath('//tr/td[3]/text()').extract()` which in the example returns `['01992 818600', '01707 364012', '01707 364003']` - which should, theoretically, be dynamic across the all the tables throughout the site?

However, what I would like to do is add service, address and phone for each table entry as a separate row in my output csv file. But I can't figure out how to split the list data my responses are returning? I have set up items which I will want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over table rows and then collect individual fields into items:

```
for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="map"]//tr[position() > 1]'):
    item = dict()
    item['service'] = row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract_first()
    item['address'] = ' '.join(x.strip() for x in row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract())
    item['phone'] = row.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract_first()
    yield item
```